# Local variable not used [JAVA]

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, local

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyCalculatorGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener { 
    JButton tripled, doubled; 
    JTextField input, output; 
    JPanel p1, p2;

MyCalculatorGUI() { 

        Container c = getContentPane(); 
        tripled = new JButton("Triple"); 
        tripled.addActionListener(this);
        doubled = new JButton("Doubled");
        doubled.addActionListener(this);
        input = new JTextField("Input a number here.");
        output = new JTextField("Result..");
        p1.add(doubled);
        p1.add(tripled);
        p2.add(input);
        p2.add(output);

        c.add(p1);
        c.add(p2);

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400,400);


    }

    public void actionListener(ActionEvent e) { 

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         MyCalculatorGUI output = new MyCalculatorGUI();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Eclipse is having a problem with my code where it is MyCalculatorGUI, it says the local variable is not used. Can somebody help me fix this?? I have recently just moved to Eclipse and everything I have tried to fix this isn't working for me.

Comment: BTW, you should put `new MyCalculatorGUI();` in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){/*...*/}};`

Comment: When I tried to edit the title, I found that there has already been a question with the title "Local variable not used." That's a *very* strong sign that this has been answered before.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have created an object and not using it anywhere in `main` method

```
MyCalculatorGUI output = new MyCalculatorGUI();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a warning by Eclipse. It cannot see that your actual logic happens inside the constructor - so it thinks you create a new object of your class `MyCalculatorGUI` inside the main method, but never use it. This could be a sign for unnecessary memory usage/consumption which might be a problem in large projects...

IF you change the line to just `new MyCalculatorGUI();` the warning will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an **error**, it's just a **warning**.

It simply means that you have created a variable which is never accessed later in the code. If you don't need it, then don't create it. If you do then just make use of it ;)

```
MyCalculatorGUI output = new MyCalculatorGUI(); //either delete this line
output.someMethod(); //or use the instance in some way
```

The warning should dissapear afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the variable you created in the `main` method, so either don't create it, use it or add the following above the `main` method: `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem, it's just an Eclipse information to inform you that your local variable is not used. You can compile with 0 problem!

To resolve the warning you have two solutions:

First:

Implement the variable:

```
MyCalculatorGUI myCalculator = new MyCalculatorGUI();
```

Second:

Use the SupressWarnings on the top of your function like that:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
 MyCalculatorGUI() { 

        Container c = getContentPane(); 
        tripled = new JButton("Triple"); 
        tripled.addActionListener(this);
        doubled = new JButton("Doubled");
        doubled.addActionListener(this);
        input = new JTextField("Input a number here.");
        output = new JTextField("Result..");
        p1.add(doubled);
        p1.add(tripled);
        p2.add(input);
        p2.add(output);

        c.add(p1);
        c.add(p2);

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400,400);
    }
```